# Abstract class that forces to hold object of type with constant name

Tags: python

I'm creating an abstract class that I want all its inheritance to hold an object of type X with the exact name.

See an example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Hands(object):
    pass

class human(ABC):

    def __init__(self):

        self.hand=Hands()

        @property
        def Hands(self):
            pass

class american_hands(Hands):
    pass


#I want to make sure that a class of type human will have a member of type hands which is called hand
class american(human):

    def __init__(self):
        self.hand=american_hands()
```

How can I force the descendants of class human to hold a member of the desired type with a predefined name?

For example, i would like anyone who is implementing class `human` without a self.hand of type Hand, would raise an error, for example, this:

```
class German(Human):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

wouldn't work.

Comment: perhaps this is what you want --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133031/python-abstract-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like

```
class Hands:
    pass


class AmericanHands(Hands):
    pass


class Human:
    hand_type = Hands

    def __init__(self):
        self.hands = self.hand_type()


class American(Human):
    hand_type = AmericanHands

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # Other American-specific initialization


h = Human()  # assert isinstance(h.hands, Hands)
a = American()  # assert isinstance(a.hands, AmericanHands)
```

The call to `super().__init__` ensures that an instance of `American` has an attribute named `hands`, while the override class attribute ensures that the type of `hands` is correct.

Comment: thanks!!! see my edit, notice that my requirement (like class german) isn't satisfied with this solution.

Comment: What's the problem? With `g = German()`, `g.hands` exists and has type `Hands`. `German.hand_type` evaluate to `Hands` via inheritance.